# Blurring an image with C

Tags: c, image

I am trying to blur an image based on the tutorial I am following. Here's the instruction.

> Blur There are a number of ways to create the effect of blurring or
> softening an image. For this problem, we’ll use the “box blur,” which
> works by taking each pixel and, for each color value, giving it a new
> value by averaging the color values of neighboring pixels.
>
> Consider the following grid of pixels, where we’ve numbered each
> pixel.
>
> a grid of pixels
>
> The new value of each pixel would be the average of the values of all
> of the pixels that are within 1 row and column of the original pixel
> (forming a 3x3 box). For example, each of the color values for pixel 6
> would be obtained by averaging the original color values of pixels 1,
> 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 11 (note that pixel 6 itself is included in
> the average). Likewise, the color values for pixel 11 would be be
> obtained by averaging the color values of pixels 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12,
> 14, 15 and 16.

> [image]

> For a pixel along the edge or corner, like pixel 15, we would still
> look for all pixels within 1 row and column: in this case, pixels 10,
> 11, 12, 14, 15, and 16.```

So to tackle this, I've come up with this solution.

```
for each row
  for each column
     add the pixel if upper left exists
     add the pixel if directly above exists
     add the pixel if upper right exists
     add the pixel if right exists
     add the pixel if directly below exists
     add the pixel if left exists
divide by times added
```

and I have typed the code -

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i + 1 && j - 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (j + 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i + 1 && j + 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i + 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (j - 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i - 1)
            {
                red = image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red/counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green/counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue/counter;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

and it seems like I am getting errors saying

```
~/pset4/filter/ $ ./filter -b images/courtyard.bmp  test.bmp                                                                                                                                                        
helpers.c:84:45: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:85:49: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:86:47: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:112:45: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:113:49: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
helpers.c:114:47: runtime error: index -1 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]'
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==4657==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fd1249a490a (pc 0x00000042b7ea bp 0x7ffd589ca4f0 sp 0x7ffd589c90f0 T4657)
==4657==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x42b7e9  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x42b7e9)
    #1 0x422ed2  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x422ed2)
    #2 0x7fd123897b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x402d69  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402d69)
```

for me it seems like the code isn't really solving the problem. It fails right out of the first iteration. because `i` and `j` value becomes negative, thus not really serving the intention of checking the nearby pixels' existence.

Could you share a point or two about what should be done here to better find out how the program should detect the surrounding pixels?

Comment: One problem with the code is that you're overwriting the input array. For example, by the time you reach pixel 6, you've already changed pixels 1,2,3 and 5. That's not how the algorithm is supposed to work. You can either use a separate output array, or a two-line buffer that stores pixels until they're no longer needed.

Comment: @user3386109 could you please elaborate on your finding? what do you mean by `separate output array` and `two-line buffer`?

Comment: Instead of `image[i][j].rgbtRed = red/counter;` at the bottom of the loop, you would write the results to a separate array, e.g. `output[i][j].rgbtRed = red/counter;`. Then, after finishing the entire image, you would `memcpy` the output array back into the input array.

Comment: Two-line buffering is more complicated, but reduces the amount of extra memory needed. Start by storing pixels 1234 in an array. Update pixels 1234 in the input array (using the stored values for the calculations). Store pixels 5678 in a second array. Update pixels 5678 using the stored values for pixels 1234 and 5678. Then replace pixels 1234 with pixels 9 10 11 12. Update pixels 9 10 11 12 using the stored values of 5678 and 9 10 11 12. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, non-zero considered as true, j-1 at j=0 is -1 true.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])

{

 int red;

int green;
int blue;
int counter = 0;
RGBTRIPLE **new_image = (RGBTRIPLE**) malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE*)*height);

  for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
     new_image[i]=((RGBTRIPLE*) malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)*width);

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
          red=green=blue=0;
          counter=0;
        if (i + 1 <height && j - 1 >=0)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        if (j + 1<width)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        if (i + 1 <height && j + 1 <width)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        if (i + 1<height)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        if (j - 1>=0)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        if (i - 1>=0)
        {
            red += image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
            green += image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
            blue += image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;
        }
        new_image[i][j].rgbtRed = red/counter;
        new_image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green/counter;
        new_image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue/counter;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: you mean reset the counter?

Comment: Yes, modified the answer, please check

Comment: Sorry it's still pitch black. :(

Comment: red,green,blue values of neighbouring pixels need to be added and values need to reset.

Comment: please check the answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202615/discussion-between-jasonthemarketer-and-venkatesh-nandigama).

Comment: The biggest problem with this answer is that it adds the pixel at `image[i][j]` in every `if` statement. The other problem is that the input array is being overwritten. See my comment under the question.

Comment: The solution isn't working.

helpers.c:80:39: error: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
RGBTRIPLE **new_image = (RGBTRIPLE**) malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE*)*height);

Comment: @JasonTheMarketer #include<stdlib.h> will help

Answer (score 2):

This is a better approach, with the possibility of increasing the blur box to others dimensions forming a 3x3 box, or others.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    double average_red = 0, average_green = 0, average_blue = 0;
    int count_number = 0;
    int box = 1; // set 1 to have a 3x3 box

    //scanning the matriz
    for (int i = 0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<width;++j)
        {
            //cleaning the averages and the count number

            average_red = 0;
            average_blue = 0;
            average_red = 0;
            count_number = 0;

            //forming a 3x3 box
            for (int li = i-box; li<=i+box; ++li )
            {
                if( li < 0 )
                {
                    li = 0;
                }
                if( li == height)
                {
                    break;
                }

                for(int col = j-box; col<= j+box; col++)
                {

                    if (col == width ) break;
                    if (col < 0)
                    {
                        col = 0;
                    }

                    count_number++;

                    average_red += image[li][col].rgbtRed;
                    average_green += image[li][col].rgbtGreen;
                    average_blue += image[li][col].rgbtBlue;

                }

            }
            //set the new average to the pixel
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = (int)round(average_red/count_number) ;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = (int)round(average_green/count_number);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (int)round( average_blue/count_number );
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This code does work per say but you want to create a parody image for the true return. otherwise your not blurring to the image data but the modified image data.

Comment: Also you would not need to use `double` for the average. With integers, it goes a lot faster and you can still calculate a rounded number by adding half of the `count_number` before the division.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am high jacking the thread.. unfortunately the solution provided did not work. the correct solution should be this.

```
    // Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE newImage[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            newImage[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, red, green, blue, counter; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            red = green = blue = counter = 0;
            // add the center pixel
            if (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
            {
                red += newImage[i][j].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add below pixel
            if (i >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += newImage[i][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add right pixel
            if ((i >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i >= 0 && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += newImage[i][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add left pixel
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j >= 0)
            {
                red += newImage[i-1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i-1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i-1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add left below pixel
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += newImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i-1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add left upper pixel
            if ((i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += newImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i-1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add upper pixel
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j >= 0))
            {
                red += newImage[i+1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i+1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i+1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add below right pixel
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j - 1 >= 0))
            {
                red += newImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i+1][j-1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            // add upper right pixel
            if ((i + 1 >= 0 && j + 1 >= 0) && (i + 1 < height && j + 1 < width))
            {
                red += newImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed;
                green += newImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += newImage[i+1][j+1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / (counter * 1.0));
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: This is the most unnecessarily complicated code for convolving an image that I've ever seen.  Why are you not using additional loops?

Comment: @paddy Thanks for the feedback. how would you tweak the code for the better? I am quite new to programming.

Comment: keep in mind though, that edge and corner cases should be considered.

Comment: For this approach, two inner loops would implicitly take care of all that testing and code duplication you're doing, and handle the edges.  Personally, I'd use a two- or three-line buffer approach so that adjacent pairs are only ever added once.

Comment: @paddy are there any good examples of `line buffer` approach? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This code works well when you consider blurring an image or n*n matxix using box blur. It considers top, bottom and middle rows and calculates the pixels RGB respectively.

```
// Blur image

void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int sumBlue;
    int sumGreen;
    int sumRed;
    //create a temporary table
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            sumBlue = 0;
            sumGreen = 0;
            sumRed = 0;
            //Top row
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == 0) //top row left corner
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);

                }

                else if (j == width - 1) //top row right corner
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else //top row middle pixel
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

            }
            //Bottom row of image
            else if (i == height - 1)
            {
                if (j == 0) //left side pixel of bottom row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else if (j == width - 1) //right side pixel of last row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                }

                else //middle pixels of last row
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

            }

            else
            {
                if (j == 0) //left side of image
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6); //6 pixels surrounding the left side of the image
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

                //Right side of image
                else if (j == width - 1)
                {
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          +  image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        +  image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                }

                else //middle pixels of middle rows
                {
                    //calculate for blue pixels
                    sumBlue = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue
                                         + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9);
                    //calculate for green pixels
                    sumGreen = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen
                                          + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9); // 9 pixels surrounding the middle one
                    //calculate for red pixels
                    sumRed = round(ceil(image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed
                                        + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 9);
                }
            }

            //assign temp values with the calculated values
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((sumBlue));
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((sumGreen));
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round((sumRed));

        }
    }

    //copies values from temporary table and assigns to original image
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            //assiging temp value to original image
            image[j][i].rgbtBlue = temp[j][i].rgbtBlue;
            image[j][i].rgbtGreen = temp[j][i].rgbtGreen;
            image[j][i].rgbtRed = temp[j][i].rgbtRed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching about this problem for two days (OMG! programming is tough and frustrating). i needed a nice logic that can help us to avoid repeating the same things over and over. Hence, I found this loop. Hope it is understandable. Please let me know if something need to be clarified. Note: include <math.h>

```
 // Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //let us a temporary one that will help us store pixels inorder to avoid overwriting any
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    //initialize temporary image structure;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }

    int blue , red, green;
    float counter;

    //loop over our image
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //initialize all variables to 0 for each new pixel
            counter = 0;
            blue = green = red = 0;

            //now for each pixel we will chech over down, up, left and right to see if it meets the condition
            //it means checking the previous, current, and next pixel
            for (int h = -1; h < 2; h++)
            {
                for (int w = -1; w < 2; w++)
                {
                    //chech if it is still inside the image to avoid memory leak or seg fault
                    if (i + h > height-1 || i + h < 0 || j + w > width-1 || j + w < 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    //if not the we must loop and add pixels at all corners of our current pixel
                    blue += image[i+h][j+w].rgbtBlue;
                    green += image[i+h][j+w].rgbtGreen;
                    red += image[i+h][j+w].rgbtRed;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            //at the end of iterations around a pixel, we must record a new pixel that we just found
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / counter);
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / counter);
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / counter);
        }
    }

    //after we finishing iterations over all pixels of our image, let modify the original image
    //recall that we were copying our findings in temp

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = temp[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = temp[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = temp[i][j].rgbtRed;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this as an absolute brute.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // making a new copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    // looping through each pixel
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
        {
            float avgRed = 0;
            float avgGreen = 0;
            float avgBlue = 0;
            // if 3x3 matrix of neighbours is possible (9 elements)
            if (h != 0 && w != 0 && (h + 1) != height && (w + 1) != width)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 9.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 9.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 9.00;
            }
            // top edge and not corner (6 elements)
            else if (h == 0 && w != 0 && (w + 1) != width)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.00;
            }

            // bottom edge and not corner ( 6 elements)
            else if (h == height - 1 && w != 0 && (w + 1) != width)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.00;
            }

            // left edge and not corner ( 6 elements)
            else if (w == 0 && h != 0 && (h + 1) != height)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 6.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.00;
            }

            // right edge and not corner (6 elements)
            else if (w == width - 1 && h != 0 && (h + 1 != height))
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) / 6.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6.00;
            }

            // top left corner ( 4 elements)
            else if (h == 0 && w == 0)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 4.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.00;
            }

            // top right corner ( 4 elements)
            else if (h == 0 && w + 1 == width)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtRed) / 4.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h + 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.00;
            }

            // bottom left corner ( 4 elements)
            else if (h + 1 == height && w == 0)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtRed) / 4.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.00;
            }
            // bottom right corner ( 4 elements)
            else if (h + 1 == height && w + 1 == width)
            {
                avgRed = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtRed + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtRed + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtRed) / 4.00;
                avgGreen = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtGreen + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4.00;
                avgBlue = (double)(copy[h][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w].rgbtBlue + copy[h - 1][w - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[h][w - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4.00;
            }
            // assigning averge values to the original image
            image[h][w].rgbtRed = round(avgRed);
            image[h][w].rgbtGreen = round(avgGreen);
            image[h][w].rgbtBlue = round(avgBlue);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, no math.h or anything. I liked how Tales's looped his.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE(*temp)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        int sumRed =0, sumBlue = 0, sumGreen =0;
        float boxsize = 0;

        for (int h = -1; h <= 1; h++)
        {
            for (int w = -1; w <= 1; w++)
            {
                if((i+h) >= 0 && height > (i+h) && (j+w) >= 0 && width > (j+w))
                {
                    sumRed += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtRed;
                    sumBlue += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtBlue;
                    sumGreen += image[i + h][j + w].rgbtGreen;
                    boxsize++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (boxsize > 0)
        {
            float avgRed = sumRed / boxsize, avgBlue = sumBlue / boxsize, avgGreen = sumGreen / boxsize;
            if ((((avgRed) - (int)avgRed) * 10) >= 5)
            {
                avgRed++;
            }
            if ((((avgBlue) - (int)avgBlue) * 10) >= 5)
            {
                avgBlue++;
            }
            if ((((avgGreen) - (int)avgGreen) * 10) >= 5)
            {
                avgGreen++;
            }
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = (uint8_t)(avgRed);
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = (uint8_t)(avgBlue);
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = (uint8_t)(avgGreen);
        }
        else
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
    }
}
free(temp);
return;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it in a simple way. This solution makes a copy of the input image so that the copy should be referred for color values, while the input image is manipulated upon to change colors. Referring to input image directly will give incorrect values as the pixel colors are changing in this image with each loop. It simplifies pixel box grid cases to be considered and resets color variables along with the counter at the end of each loop. As the saying goes, the most simple solution which comes to mind, is generally the best one. Hope it helps.

`

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];  //create a copy of the image 
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height)
            {
                red += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (j + 1 < width)
            {
                red += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height && j + 1 < width)
            {
                red += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i + 1 < height && j - 1 >= 0)
            {
                red += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < width)
            {
                red += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;
            }
            red += copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            green += copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            blue += copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            counter++;

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green / (counter * 1.0));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue / (counter * 1.0));

            red = 0;
            green = 0;
            blue = 0;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

`